# angular load ui-bootstrap tabbed content dynamically

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular ui-bootstrap tabs for developing tabs.
But how I load tabbed data dynamically after each tab click.

I am able to load the static content. But I want to load data dynamically from ajax.
**Each tab containing different HTML files.**

### controller

```
  $scope.customerInfoTabs = 
           {  
              "General":[  
                 "General",
                 "Employment",
                 "Relationship Status",
              ],
              "Identification":[]                
           }
$scope.customerInfo = $scope.customerInfoTabs['General'];
```

### template

```
<div class="well">            
            <div class="tabbable">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">                               
                <li ng-class="{'active': $index == 0}" ng-repeat="infotabs in customerInfo"><a showtab="" href= data-toggle="tab" ng-click="">{{infotabs}}</a></li>              
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content">                
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                  <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                  <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                  <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 3.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show dynamic content for each tab you will need to use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service to fetch the html, then bind it using [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Here is how:

```
<tabset>
   <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}"  select="loadData()">
      <div ng-bind-html="tabDynamicContent"></div>
   </tab>
</tabset>
```

The above example is a simplification where all the tabs will have the same html. Also make sure you include the [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module.

Here is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yege43KerzfFKE8k5OGc?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think this question was answer by this stackoverflow:
[first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102153/angularjs-bootstrap-tabset-tab-heading) or [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850470/how-to-add-dynamic-contents-to-tab-set-using-angular-and-ui-bootstrap)

So you could use a tab set in order to do the work you need.